# Flutter qr_code_scanner how to pause camera when i switch tab in my CupertinoTabView?

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode, barcode-scanner

I use the flutter qr_code_scanner package, my page with the QR code scanner is inside the CupertinoTabView tab, I want the camera to be paused when the tab is changed, and when the tab with the scanner is reopened, it continues to work, how can I implement this?

I tried to do it through the global key of my QRView but that doesn't work either because the currentState of my key is always null and I can't call the method that would pause the camera

```
// my ScannerWidget 
final GlobalKey<QRScannerState> qrKey = GlobalKey<QRScannerState>(debugLabel: 'QR');

class QRScannerState extends State<QRScanner> {
  late QRViewController controller;
  String _scannedData = '';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        QRView(
          key: qrKey,
          onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
            ),
            child: const Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text('|||', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 80),),
                Text('  |||', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 80),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const CustomPaintContainer(),
        if (_scannedData.isNotEmpty)
          Positioned(
            bottom: 16,
            left: 16,
            right: 16,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                    blurRadius: 4,
                    offset: const Offset(0, 2),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Text(
                _scannedData,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void pauseCamera(){
    controller.pauseCamera();
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        _scannedData = scanData.code!;
      });
      if(scanData != ''){
        HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
        controller.pauseCamera();
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          CupertinoPageRoute(
            fullscreenDialog: true,
            builder: (context) => GlobalScanScreen(
              scanData: scanData.code!,
            ),
          ),
        ).then((value) => controller.resumeCamera());
      }
    });
  }
```

My CupertinoTabView page:

```
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return !await tabNavKeys[_controller.index].currentState!.maybePop();
      },
      child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
          controller: _controller,
          key: myKey,
          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            onTap: onItemTapped,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.house),
                  activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.house_fill)),
              // create tab for scanner
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code_scanner)),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person),
                  activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person_fill)),
            ],
          ),
          tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                return const HomePage();
              case 1:
                return const BarcodeScannerPage();
              case 2:
                return CupertinoTabView(
                  navigatorKey: tabNavKeys[index],
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => const ProfilePage(),
                );
              default:
                return Container();
            }
          }),
    );
```